# Placement of 'Cancel' action on an iOS navigation bar in a modal view?

Tags: buttons, ios, modal-view

In the case of two actions such as **Cancel** and **Done**, I would usually place Done on top-right and Cancel on the left. In the case of a single action such as Done, I would usually place it on the top-right as well.

But where should the **Cancel** action be placed when it is the *only action* on a modal view? Should it be placed on top left or top right?

Comment: Anyone please...?

Comment: Could you please provide a mockup that you have done? Also, have you read this one? https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/interaction/modality/

Answer (score 4):

UX Guidelines suggest that the **primary action** for every page/activity should be placed at the right-most corner (top or bottom, depending upon design language).

In your case it seems like it is an alert modal with the only action being *Cancel*. By the UX rule, *Cancel* here is the primary action. So it goes in the rightmost corner.

Example :-
[image: Example of iOS navigation modal with only Cancel as the action. It is placed on the rightmost corner]

### UPDATE

I realized that I hadn't provided a source for my answer. Unfortunately, I am unable to find the exact source of the image above so I am adding a few references (including that from the Apple Developer Guide)

[image: Cancel button placement in temporary screens in iOS. Top-right for search]

**Sources**

[Apple Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/bars/search-bars/)

[UXPlanet reference](https://uxplanet.org/mobile-ux-design-user-friendly-search-51e5f78f5a1e)

Comment: Can you please provide a link to your "UX guidelines"?  I could find nothing in the Apple iOS Human Interface Guidelines about this. Other references I found on the web often said to *avoid* using the top right because it is outside the reachable thumb zone (even though it is used by Apple apps?). Citation needed ;-)

Comment: @robocat - Updated my answer

Comment: Your answer relates to **search bars**, which is not relevant to the question which is about a navigation bar. Here is [an article](https://medium.com/tall-west/lets-ditch-the-nav-bar-3692cb17cc67) suggesting to avoid navbar buttons due to reachability. There is a detailed [article on alistapart about device reachability](https://alistapart.com/article/how-we-hold-our-gadgets) with references to research - other articles sometimes make up their facts!

Comment: @robocat - I completely agree on the reach-ability issue. But it's sometimes unavoidable on a phone that doesn't have any physical or on-screen buttons. The reason I picked the Search Bar example was because it tackled the issue of *having two actions on the navigation bar*. We don't have that in most cases and especially in modals. I am just quoting Apple's standards here -> https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/bars/navigation-bars/  This still mentions that actions should be placed on the top-left when there's a Back button on the top-left

Comment: And personally, I would avoid putting actions on the navigation bar but with the current phone sizes, single-handed use has gone for a toss. Also, the double-tap to lower the top section is the current solution on iOS devices